# Is there a way to infuse the input variable in regex?

Tags: python, regex

EDIT: So apparently, this is a string interpolation in regex. Thanks for clarifying.

I have a input function that is named omj.

```
omj
```

When I run it, it gives me

```
"obik"
```

I then use that output in this regex function

```
re.findall("\w*obik\w*",dataframe)
```

I received **EXACTLY** what I wanted, which is the answer

```
"Yaobikuni"
```

Notice that "obik" is in the word, and there is only one match for it. Is there a way to put the input omj in the regex function to get Yaobikuni straightforwardly, or is this the only way it would work?

EDIT: I don't understand why people are downvoting, but I thought I made it clear that omj can be considered as an input string that gives the answer obik.

```
omj = """obik"""
```

**EDIT2**: Thank you for the help @Nick Chapman . I tried this on the first time and I thought it might not have been possible to infuse the input omj on an regex function:

```
re.findall("\w*"omj"\w*",dataframe)
```

Comment: This is very confusing. Can you clarify your input/output/question? What is `omj`: Is it's a function or an input?

Comment: @ctwheels: It's an input, and I get obik as an output when running it.

Comment: So if it's an input and you get an output of `obik` from it it's a function? How does `omj === obik`?

Comment: @ctwheels: it's a function that gives obik that I equate it to omj. Therefore, you may conclude that omj = """obik"""

Comment: So one could say that `omj` is a function similar to `def omj():
    print("obik")`?

Comment: @ctwheels:  Yes, and it's an output. If I did omj, dataframe again, my output will still be obik.

Comment: @SunnyLeague I think the goal of the question is a little confusing.  If you could start with what exactly you're trying to accomplish you may get better responses.  It seems that maybe you're trying to directly pass the output of the function into the regex?

Comment: @SunnyLeague you should also use `re.escape()` on `omj` to ensure you're not adding special regex characters to the regex (you'll get incorrect results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
re.findall("\w*" + omj + "\w*",dataframe)
```

Comment: Without a pair of parenthesis after `omj()` this would fail fail with `TypeError: must be str, not function`

Comment: I don't believe that `omj` is a function in this case, just a string.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is just a string, so your real question is how to do string interpolation in Python.

How about this:

```
re.findall("\w*{}\w*".format(omj()), dataframe)
```

Comment: I believe I clarified it again in my first edit, but thank you. This works for functions.